# Can schema be ignored in object names in VS 2010 Schema Compare?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, schema-compare

Is it possible to ignore the schema in object names when comparing databases using Visual Studio 2010 Schema Compare? For example, I'd like `[dbo].[mysproc]` and `[mysproc]` to be considered equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these references in stored procedures?

I don't think that there's any way of achieving this. As far as I'm aware stored procedures are compared textually, rather than semantically.

Comment: These occur all over the place, often when defining object names, eg, `CREATE PROC [dbo].[mysproc]` vs. `CREATE PROC [mysproc]`.

Comment: I've just reproduced this in VS2010 and can't see a way round it. To plug the product I work on, Red Gate SQL Compare, this will ignore the schema as long as they're just in the object name declaration. However, in the textual body of an object, SQL Compare will also highlight these as differences. If you give this a go, you'll get fewer false positives to trawl through.